# Is there significance to the golden ratio occurring in Quranic verses?

Tags: quran

I have come across a defunct website. It claims that summation of abjad values of the first verses of all Suras is 223607 (including Basmala in Al Fatihah) which coincide with numerals of 2 times Golden Ratio minus 1. (Or to put it in other way, golden ratio plus part of golden ratio after the the decimal point)

The odds seem to be one in a million. I know how to calculate abjad values but I am slow and the work to verify seems a bit tedious.

Any volunteers to verify or refute this claim?

https://web.archive.org/web/20110616225746/http://www.yaratan.com/sibernetik/posters_ayet.htm

Comment: On StackExchange sites, we're encouraged to vote according to the usefulness of the question.  I.e., "Is it understandable?", "would someone else Google this question?", "can it be answered?", that kind of thing.  If the answer is "no" (or even "NOOOO!!!!"), then I suggest either answering it, or upvoting an answer you agree with.

Comment: Thank you Rebecca. Down-voting is unfair for this question. I guess members of this specific site are not familiar with math a lot. This is a cool question if you really understand it.

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones I can't speak for the downvoters, but voting is *also* encouraged according to the research effort shown in the question: "I read a thing, and verifying it is tedious. Can anyone do it for me?" doesn't really demonstrate that.

Comment: @goldPseudo Probably you do not think much about the power of networking. Certain work which is tedious for someone can and most probably be easily done by someone else. I recognize the arabic script but i am really slow. I am not a native. This is for the record.

Answer (score 3):

> summation of abjad values of the first verses of all Suras

What's the significance of it being a summation rather than, say, a product? Or a division? Or any other mathematical operation?

What's the significance of it being the abjad values rather than some other function of the character position?

What's the significance of the first verses of all Suras? Why not the second verses? Or the last versus? Or just the first character? Or the last character?

The answer is: there is nothing special about any of these operations *a priori*.

> which coincide with numerals of 2 times Golden Ratio minus 1

What's significant about this particular number? I mean, there's an infinite number of mathematically significant numbers. For instance, you can write *any* sequence of numbers and one could find some multiple of pi that matches it.

---

The broader point is: if you're looking for *any* arbitrary rule that maps words to numbers, and *any* arbitrary rule that maps that number to something that appears mathematically significant, then *every* book will be full of an *infinite* number of such coincidences, so your hunch that "the odds seem to be one in a million" is baseless.